# How to detect that extern "C" is in effect

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, extern

I am trying to find all places where `#include` is placed inside `extern` **C** block. Is is possible to check this using preprocessor? I would like to do add something like this to my header files:

```
#ifdef EXTERN_C_IS_IN_EFFECT
#error File included from extern "C" block!
#endif
```

I am also looking for other ways to fail compilation in such case, e.g. use some special attribute. I am using gcc 4.4.7.

I defined following macro and then use it in every header which needs protection against inclusion in `extern` **C** block:

```
#define ASSERT_NO_EXTERN_C void assert_no_extern_c(int); void assert_no_extern_c(double);
```

Comment: `extern` isn't noticed by the preprocessor at all.

Comment: If you need this to find all files where you have an extern "C"-block you could take your code project with all files to be searched to your favourite IDE and do a "Search in whole Project/Solution/..."

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hm. `#define extern static`?

Comment: I think I have an idea how to solve the problem that might have led you to your current problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you can define 2 function prototypes with same name and different parameters. You will get warnings in case of extern "C" block. And it is allowed in C++.

Comment: Thanks! This works for me: void assert_no_extern_c(int); void assert_no_extern_c(double);

Answer (score 8):

That's not possible because the preprocessor runs before any syntactical analysis is done; that is, the preprocessor doesn't even know what `extern "C"` is and it's action cannot depend on the presence of such a directive either.

However, linkage specifications do nest, so instead of making sure the includer did not specify `extern "C"`, you could place your header within an `extern "C++"` specification to make sure that it uses C++ linkage.